# Extracting Component Html Css Js from a React App

Tags: reactjs

I have a React application which consists of multiple different components.

I would like to extract an arbitrary component and generate static `html/css/js` for this component.

Some components rely on dependencies, some components `<App />` can be the whole application.

Is this possible? (I looked at webpack without success)

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed posible, but you cannot use the import css because this time, you are not going to use webpack.

Steps:

1. initialize a directory:

```
npm i react react-dom
```

2. create a CommonJS component:

const React = require('react');

```
export default function App() {
    return <h1>Hello World</h1>
}
```

3. Use ReactDOM.renderToString